# AJAX Permission Denied On IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser

I'm trying to make an ajax call to an external domain that is already allowing external requests by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header, but i get Permission Denied on the `xmlhttp.post()` line.

Here is my code:

```
var xmlhttp;
try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
        xmlhttp = false;
    }
}

if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp = false;
    }
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.domain.com", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in IE, you still can't use `XMLHttpRequest` for cross domain requests. For that, you need to use `XDomainRequest` object. Full documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28VS.85%29.aspx). I believe the reason for introducing the separate object was to allow developers to do a compatibility test before making a request that certainly would fail with older browsers.

Comment: Hi Andrew, i've used XDomainRequest and it works, but now it gives me setRequestHeader is not supported

Comment: Ah. Yes. That method is not supported. I've never had to set that header before. If you are trying to get the submission to show up as a form submission rather than a query string submission, change your `"GET"` to `"POST"`.

Comment: I'm actually sending a json variable in POST, but the server never receive it without setting that header.

Comment: Weird. I thought that was the only way POST submissions were recognized by the server. Are you able to grab the raw request so you can see what headers are getting set in the POST submissions? I don't have Windows running now, but you may be able to see the request as it leaves the browser in the Developer window. Failing that Fiddler2 should be able to grab it (and should be more accurate).

Comment: Sorry. According to [this](http://www.actionmonitor.co.uk/news/5/using-xdomainrequest-post-requests-with-asp.net), you may be hosed unless you also control the server-side script. Kind of makes you wonder why anyone would include XDomainRequest if it basically only worked reliably for GETs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only use Ajax with URL's form the same domain as your calling page. It's not the external domain that disallows the request, it's your browser's security. Take a look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
This is a way to avoid cross browser scripts - otherwise imagine you have a page where you can enter your credit card info and someone injects a script that sends information you are typing to an external site. Would be a big problem to fight.

Comment: The header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*' at the top of the question should allow browsers to access content across domains (in those browser that recognize it). IE8 should, but I don't think IE7 does. FireFox added support around version 3.5, so coverage is far from complete.

Answer (score 0):

Note :Do not use "http://domain.xxx" or "http://localhost/" or "IP" for URL in Ajax.
Only use path(directory) and page name without address.

**false state:**

```
var AJAXobj = createAjax();
AJAXobj.onreadystatechange = handlesAJAXcheck;
AJAXobj.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/page.php', true);
AJAXobj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
AJAXobj.send(pack);
```

**true state:**

```
var AJAXobj = createAjax();
AJAXobj.onreadystatechange = handlesAJAXcheck;
AJAXobj.open('POST','dir1/dir2/page.php', true);   // <<--- note
AJAXobj.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
AJAXobj.send(pack);
```

---

```
function createAjax()
{
    var ajaxHttp = null;
    try
    {
        if(typeof ActiveXObject == 'function')
            ajaxHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        else 
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            ajaxHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
        return null;
    }
    //-------------
    return ajaxHttp;
};
```