# Javascript security stopping me?

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm pretty sure it's a security issue keeping me from doing this, but I wonder if there's a workaround I don't know of...

I have a script to inject a user's email into the contact DB of my client and it's bombing in IE but working in FF, Chrome (as usual).  Just wondering if I can add the server to the trust or something to make it work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = init;

    //Global XMLHTTP Request object
    var XmlHttp;
    function CreateXmlHttp() {
        //Creating object of XMLHTTP in IE
        try {
            XmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                XmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (ex) {
                XmlHttp = null;
            }
        }
        //Creating object of XMLHTTP in Mozilla and Safari
        if (!XmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
            XmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    }

    function init() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName("btnContinue");
        x[0].onclick = submitForm;
    }

    function submitForm() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName('Email');
        if (x[0].value.length > 0) {
            CreateXmlHttp();
            XmlHttp.open("POST", "https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php", false);
            XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            XmlHttp.send("redirect='http://www.xyz.com/articles.asp?ID=97'&errorredirect='http://www.xyz.com/articles.asp?ID=256'&fields_email=" +
                x[0].value + "&listid=123&specialid:123=YP7I&clientid=123&formid=123&reallistid=1&doubleopt=0&Submit=Submit");
        }
    }

</script>
```

I'd appreciate any insight.

Thanks!

Comment: this would be alot less code using ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Looks like it might be a same-origin policy issue.  If you have access to https://app.icontact.com/ you could try setting the Access-Control-Request-Headers to allow your domain to make a POST request.

Comment: I'm a bit constrained as I am working on a page I really don't have control of.  The page is hosted on one of those 3rd party site builders that only allows injection of code through predefined areas on the page...sort of hacking it.  So I really can't create new forms or import libraries unless they're all hidden. I should note this worked in Firefox just fine.  Only bombing in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE?  I think only the XMLHttpRequest obeys the Access-Control-Request-Headers, which means that if IE isn't using them, it would be violating the same-origin policy and not working.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to try creating `XMLHttpRequest` *before* ActiveX Objects. IE7 and up DO support AJAX the way other browsers do.

Next, you should use relative paths in the `open()` method. Although I think form your question it's something that'll need to be able to run on any site? In that case I'd suggest creating a form and an iframe and using the "old" method.

Answer (score 0):

It is a same-origin policy issue.  The allow access content headers may be set, but the IE ActiveXObject won't use them.  XMLHttpRequests obey the headers and will work on browsers that support them.

See this question:
[AJAX Permission Denied On IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772019/ajax-permission-denied-on-ie)

Though it doesn't look like they found a solution for an IE compatible cross-domain POST...

If you could proxy it through your web server (Make a POST to your server), and have the server make the POST, your problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

On new browsers, you can use cross-domain XHR if you can have a special HTTP header on the page you request.
http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-site-xmlhttprequest/

Or you can use dynamic script loading.